# .cshtml in class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to use RazorEngine for rendering views for emails, but I can't seem to get views working in class library.

I followed this blog https://conficient.wordpress.com/2013/11/27/asp-net-razor-views-in-class-libraries/ but it still doesn't recognize .cshtml files.

I also tried https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/IntellisenseAndResharper.html but I always get errors about .cshtml and how RazorEngine is in a assembly that isn't referenced but it's in references.

I know there isn't much to go with, but does anyone have views in class library working?

EDIT:[image][image]

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
<sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
  <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
  <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
 </configSections>

   <system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="MyNamespace" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
 </appSettings>

  <system.web>
<compilation targetFramework="4.5">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
 </system.web>

<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
  <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
</handlers>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Try posting some of the errors you're getting. That might help diagnose what the exact problem is.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I updated the question.

Comment: I would suggest using what is already available ([Postal](http://aboutcode.net/postal/outside-aspnet.html) comes to mind). The [samples](https://github.com/andrewdavey/postal/tree/master/src/Samples) directory has (surprise!) an example of generating emails in, say, a console application.

Comment: @TiesonT. but even with Postal I need to add .cshtml files to class library and I still don't have intellisense in them. I was planning on using RazorEngine but first I need to be able to edit cshtml files.